# SQL - Writing an order by case or if statement

Tags: php, mysql

**Some beforehand layout knowledge about the database**

I have a database with my store items that has the following four fields

```
`c.postdate`, `c.regularprice`, `c.isonsale`, `c.saleprice`
```

The standard call to the database is something like the following:

```
query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE `s.cat` IN (idsarrayishere) AND `s.isactive` = '1' $sort")
```

This works to just pull everything from the database. The default value for `$sort` is just blank since I am not worried about that at this time as I will most likely just sort them by newest date using the `c.postdate` field listed above.

**Sorting items by specific variables**

I would love to be able to take advantage of the `ORDER BY CASE` that mysql has to be able to sort my items from `price highest - lowest` and vice versa. The issue I am running into is I don't know how to write the query so that if the `c.isonsale = '1'` then order by the the `c.saleprice` instead of the `c.regularprice`, and if it's not, order by the `c.regularprice`, so when they select lowest price first, it will show them the sale items in with the lower priced items. This is what I've found so far for `ORDER BY` with case

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE `type` 
        WHEN 'Member' THEN LNAME 
        WHEN 'Group' THEN GROUPNAME
        ELSE 1 END 
ASC
```

Not sure the correct way to adapt this to what I am trying to do though. Any help on this matter would be appreciated as the MySQL doc's are a little vague when learning this process.

**Edit**

In response to the reply about adding sample data and expected result since my post isn't clear about this apparently, say I have these three items

```
item => 1
   c.regularprice => 9.99
   c.isonsale => 0
   c.saleprice => 0

item => 2
   c.regularprice => 19.99
   c.isonsale => 1
   c.saleprice => 6.99

item => 3
   c.regularprice => 10.99
   c.isonsale => 0
   c.saleprice => 0
```

I need to be able to sort by price lowest first, then go to highest. So with this example, I would expect `item 2, item 1, item 3` in that order. Even though the regular price of item 2 is higher than the others, its on sale and cheaper so should show first.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: I have edited the original post and added some sample examples for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only switching between two possible options, I think [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) will be simpler than `CASE`.

```
ORDER BY IF(c.isonsale, c.saleprice, c.regularprice)
```

That `IF` expression will return the sale price if the item is on sale, and the regular price if it isn't.

Comment: I have edited the original post to add some sample example of expected output on the bottom. Would this `order by` still apply for that operation?

Comment: Awesome, i'll test it out quick and accept if it works how I think it should. cheers mate.